# How to perform complex multicolumn match in R /

Tags: r, dataframe, matching

I wish to match two dataframes based on conditionals on more than one column but cannot figure out how. So if there are my data sets:

```
df1 <- data.frame(lower=c(0,5,10,15,20), upper=c(4,9,14,19,24), x=c(12,45,67,89,10))
df2 <- data.frame(age=c(12, 14, 5, 2, 9, 19, 22, 18, 23))
```

I wish to match age from df2 that falls into the range between lower and upper in df1 with the aim to add an extra column to df2 containing the value of x in df1 where age lies between upper and lower. i.e. I want df2 to look like

```
age    x
12    67
14    67
 5    45
....etc.
```

How can I achieve such a match ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would go with a simple `sapply` and a "anded" condition in the `df1$x` selection like this:

```
df2$x <- sapply( df2$age, function(x) { df1$x[ x >= df1$lower & x <= df1$upper ] })
```

which gives:

```
> df2
  age  x
1  12 67
2  14 67
3   5 45
4   2 12
5   9 45
6  19 89
7  22 10
8  18 89
9  23 10
```

For age 12 for example the selection inside the brackets gives:

```
> 12 >= df1$lower & 12 <= df1$upper
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

So getting `df1$x` by this logical vector is easy as your ranges don't overlap

Comment: Thanks Tensibai I like it. Yeah I constructed that way on purpose. In my real data its not quite so clean, but I can easily work around it. I like the use of >= and <= I find that easier to read than the other solutions.

Answer (score 6):

Using `foverlaps` from `data.table` is what you are looking for:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)[,age2:=age]
setkey(df1,lower,upper)
foverlaps(df2, df1, by.x = names(df2),by.y=c("lower","upper"))[,list(age,x)]

#    age  x
# 1:  12 67
# 2:  14 67
# 3:   5 45
# 4:   2 12
# 5:   9 45
# 6:  19 89
# 7:  22 10
# 8:  18 89
# 9:  23 10
```

Comment: Thanks agstudy. Very nice. Is it bad that I prefer the sapply version posted by Tensabai - I'm not currently using data.table in my project and I like that it keeps it in base r

Answer (score 6):

Here's another vectorized approach using `findInterval` on a melted data set

```
library(data.table) 
df2$x <- melt(setDT(df1), "x")[order(value), x[findInterval(df2$age, value)]]
#   age  x
# 1  12 67
# 2  14 67
# 3   5 45
# 4   2 12
# 5   9 45
# 6  19 89
# 7  22 10
# 8  18 89
# 9  23 10
```

The idea here is to

- First, tidy up you data so `lower` and `upper` will be in the same column and `x` will have corresponding values to that new column,
- Then, sort the data according to these ranges (necessary for `findInterval`).
- Finally, run `findInterval` within the `x` column in order to find the correct incidences

---

And here's a possible `dplyr`/`tidyr` version

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  gather(variable, value, -x) %>%
  arrange(value) %>%
  do(data.frame(x = .$x[findInterval(df2$age, .$value)])) %>%
  cbind(df2, .)
#   age  x
# 1  12 67
# 2  14 67
# 3   5 45
# 4   2 12
# 5   9 45
# 6  19 89
# 7  22 10
# 8  18 89
# 9  23 10
```

Comment: Thanks David. Also very nice. Again my preference (possibly irrationally) is for the base R sapply version

Comment: Yeah, you can use what ever version you prefer, though `sapply` isn't vectorized and potentially slower for a big data set.

Comment: Ok thanks David. In this particular instance the data set is small. But I will bear that i mind in future. Thanks for your input!