# R: replace value with value from interval list

Tags: r

using R I calculate age based on a combination of distributions. This age is then linked to a centrain life-expectancy which is listed in a table (or whatever the most convenient way is) like this:

```
age exp_life
0-5     80
6-10    75.38
11-15   70.4
16-20   65.41
21-25   60.44
26-30   etc..
```

So for example age 7 corresponds with 75.38, how do I easily program in R to look this up?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It is not clear.   Perhaps check `?merge` or `?match`

Comment: Or look up how to provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Not really clear what you want. You have some age RANGES (and not age VALUES) that are linked to an "exp_life" value. You want to be able to link age values to "exp_life" values? Like: age value 7 belongs to age range 6-10 so it's linked to exp_life value 75.38?

Comment: That is right, i want to replace a VALUE with a VALUE (exp_life) from RANGE (age) so: value 7 is in range 6-10 and therefore replaced with 75.38

Comment: you can have a look [there](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/32221224/how-to-perform-complex-multicolumn-match-in-r). I believe your problem is very similar

Comment: Thank you CathG, that matches indeed the question. Haven't found it before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `findInterval()` to find the `exp_life` corresponding to the `age` interval.

With a setup similar to the previous answer (but no need to create an entire lookup table -- if your age input is not an integer this won't work anyway).

```
df <- read.table(header=TRUE,
                text="age     exp_life
                      0-5     80
                      6-10    75.38
                      11-15   70.4
                      16-20   65.41
                      21-25   60.44
                      26-30   etc..",
                stringsAsFactors =FALSE)

library(tidyr); library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  separate(age, into=c('from_age','to_age'), sep='-') %>%
  mutate_each(funs(as.numeric)) %>%
  arrange(from_age) -> df # in case it's not sorted

df$exp_life[findInterval(7, df$from_age)] # returns [1] 75.38
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a process that uses packages `dplyr` and `tidyr` in order to produce a new dataset that has info on an "age range" level and "age value" level:

```
# example dataset
dt = read.table(text=
"age exp_life
0-5     80
6-10    75.38
11-15   70.4
16-20   65.41
21-25   60.44", header=T)

library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

dt %>% 
  separate(age, c("low","high")) %>%                # split your range values into low and high
  mutate(low = as.numeric(low),                     # make those columns numeric
         high = as.numeric(high)) %>%
  rowwise() %>%                                      # for each row
  do(data.frame(.,
                age_val=seq(.$low,.$high,1))) %>%    # get all possible age values and combine them with ranges and exp_life values
  ungroup

#    low high exp_life age_val
# 1    0    5    80.00       0
# 2    0    5    80.00       1
# 3    0    5    80.00       2
# 4    0    5    80.00       3
# 5    0    5    80.00       4
# 6    0    5    80.00       5
# 7    6   10    75.38       6
# 8    6   10    75.38       7
# 9    6   10    75.38       8
# 10   6   10    75.38       9
# 11   6   10    75.38      10
# 12  11   15    70.40      11
# 13  11   15    70.40      12
# 14  11   15    70.40      13
# 15  11   15    70.40      14
# 16  11   15    70.40      15
# 17  16   20    65.41      16
# 18  16   20    65.41      17
# 19  16   20    65.41      18
# 20  16   20    65.41      19
# 21  16   20    65.41      20
# 22  21   25    60.44      21
# 23  21   25    60.44      22
# 24  21   25    60.44      23
# 25  21   25    60.44      24
# 26  21   25    60.44      25
```

Comment: This is not a great solution because you create an unnecessarily large lookup table when all you need to do is check the intervals.  You do not need "all possible age values" in a table.  Also, this lookup approach does not work for fractional ages (10.5, etc).

Comment: I agree that "findInterval" makes it more general and much better in the case where you don't need a look up table. I've wrongly assumed that the age values would be integers and as a consequence a look up table is not a big problem as it won't have many rows.